# Can't log in normally or through tty after changing Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: boot, nvidia, data-recovery, tty, gpu-driver

I switched from a 1070GTX to a 1080TI a week ago. And while I did all the steps necessary for the switch on Windows, I forgot to do anything on my Ubuntu partition.

I tried to log in today and well I couldn't. I got a black screen. 
I tried to log in to tty1-7 and while I was able to get the login prompt there the computer didn't take inputs after that.

I then tried again in recovery mode GRUB->ADVANCED OPTIONS->UBUNTU 16.XXX (Recovery).
I went through the resume boot option and the same thing happened.
I tried the Graphics Failsafe Mode or something like that and I got a screen with messages scattered, the last of these was something like "Nvidia Persistence Daemon STOPPED". It was unresponsive though and I couldn't get into a tty log in prompt.

I don't know where to go from here. I'm ok with nuking the system since I'm upgrading motherboard/cpu in a week or two, but I have data in there that I'd like to rescue from the low orbit attack I'll be doing. I can still log into windows but I can't rescue anything in the User folder for some reason. I think it's possibly encrypted.

In any case, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your Nvidia driver on Linux to version 381 which is not available in the normal apt sources. You should however be able to recover as follows.

- Get yourself a LiveUsb or LiveDvd.
- Boot from it and take the option to run  Ubuntu from it.
- When Ubuntu desktop appears, start the terminal app to get a command line.
- Run the following commands, one at a time

  - mkdir myd
  - sudo lsblk
  - Comment to determine which disk contains the Linux system. Frequently /dev/sdax
  - Coment but may be different because you have a dual boot system.
  - sudo mount /dev/sdx myd
  - sudo chroot myd bash
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
  - sudo apt update
  - sudo apt install nvidia-381
  - exit

Now you can reboot into your normal Linux system and hopefully all will be good. See http://blog.nelsonliu.me/2017/04/29/installing-and-updating-gtx-1080-ti-cuda-drivers-on-ubuntu/[1](http://blog.nelsonliu.me/2017/04/29/installing-and-updating-gtx-1080-ti-cuda-drivers-on-ubuntu/) for more details.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a go. I actually don't know where my Linux Partition is at. I know it's in disk 3 but it's weirdly formatted. System Reserved - C: (Windows) - 150GB Partition - 8GB Partition (Swap?) - 37 GB partition. I guess I'm gonna have to go through backup procedures first just in case.

Comment: You might want to run gdisk from the LiveUsb to try and help you determine what partition is what. Use the p command to get summay information and the l command to get detailed information about partitions you are unsure of. This asumes that your system is a modern one with GPT parrtition tables. You might also want to run Disk Management from Windows to get a Windows perspective on your system.